# Sed on windows cannot match £ character

Tags: windows, sed

Created a text file with Notepad++ with a `£` sign - UK currency.
Cannot persuade SED to match it using:

```
sed -i -r "s/£/NEWCHAR/g" %OutFile%
```

Tried encoding as ANSI and UTF-8, all the Western European options - none worked. Any ideas?

Using Windows 7 Pro 64-bit

Comment: Are you using WSL? Not sure why there's a windows tag.

Comment: Try `sed -i -r "s/\xA3/NEWCHAR/g" %OutFile%`